# How do I get error information from Infiniband verbs functions?

Tags: infiniband, rdma

In particular, I'd like to know why ibv_create_qp fails. When it returns NULL, indicating that it failed, is there a way to find out exactly what the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a lot of information I guess.

You could start by looking at the `errno` value. It might provide some clue, although I believe most errors will result in a generic `EINVAL`. If you are willing to step-through libibverbs with a debugger you could get more information. Some errors occur inside the kernel driver and require investigating the relevant kernel modules. Maybe your device's kernel driver has some debugging prints that can be enabled?